# Getting Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection ERROR in docker image of kafka

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, docker-compose, keystore, confluent-platform

I'm trying to setup SSL in Kafka using docker image. I'm getting below weird ERROR after configuring. Since I'm unable to understand what's the issue and still figuring out what happening here. Any help highly appreciated.

I have generate kafka1_keystore.jks and truststore.jks keystore and added kafka1.crt (server certificate ) and root.crt (root certificate ) inside keystore of both jks.

Still SSL handshake is failing.

> Error

[image]

I'm not sure which plaintext kafka is trying to connect using SSL.

Below is my zookeeper and kafka docker compose yml files.

> zookeeper.yml

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  zoo1:
  image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.0.0
  hostname: zoo1
  ports:
    - 2191:2181
  networks:
    - cms-overlay
  environment:
    ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 1
    ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: zoo1:2888:3888
    ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
    ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    ZOOKEEPER_INIT_LIMIT: 5
    ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: 2
  deploy:
    replicas: 1
    restart_policy:
      condition: any
    placement:
      constraints:
        - node.labels.kafka==kafka1
  volumes:
     - /var/lib/zookeeper/1/data:/var/lib/zookeeper/data
     - /var/lib/zookeeper/1/logs:/var/lib/zookeeper/logs
     - /var/lib/zookeeper/1/datalog:/var/lib/zookeeper/datalog
     - /var/lib/zookeeper/1/log:/var/lib/zookeeper/log
   
  networks:
    cms-overlay:
    external: true
```

> kafka.yml file

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  kafka1:
  image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka:7.0.0
  ports:
    - 9192:9192
deploy:
  replicas: 1
  restart_policy:
    condition: any
  placement:
    constraints:
      - node.labels.kafka==kafka1
networks:
  - cms-overlay
environment:
  JAVA_OPTS : "-Xms6g -Xmx6g -XX:MetaspaceSize=96m -XX:+UseG1GC - 
    XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20
   -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=16M
   -XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio=50 -XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=80 " 
  KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
  KAFKA_LISTENERS: ISSL://:29092,OSSL://:9192
  KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zoo1:2181
  KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: ISSL:SSL,OSSL:SSL
  KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: ISSL
  KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: 
   ISSL://kafka1:29092,OSSL://172.16.41.11:9192
  KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: "true"
  KAFKA_NUM_PARTITIONS: 3
  KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: 
   io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
  KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
  KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
  KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
  KAFKA_DEFAULT_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
  KAFKA_MIN_INSYNC_REPLICAS: 1
  KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 100
  KAFKA_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL: INFO
  CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka1:29092
  CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zoo1:2181
  CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
  CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'true'
  CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: 'anonymous'
  KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_FILENAME: kafka1_keystore.jks
  KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_CREDENTIALS: kafka_secret.txt
  KAFKA_SSL_KEY_CREDENTIALS: kafka_secret.txt
  KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_FILENAME: truststore.jks
  KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_CREDENTIALS: trust_secret.txt
  KAFKA_SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM: ""
  KAFKA_LISTENER_NAME_INTERNAL_SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM: ""
  KAFKA_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH: required
  KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_PROTOCOL: SSL
  KAFKA_JMX_OPTS: "
   -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/etc/kafka/secrets/truststore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/etc/kafka/secrets/kafka1_keystore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=kafka123 -Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.object.disableEndpointIdentification=true -Djavax.net.debug=all"
volumes:
  - /var/lib/kafka/1/data:/var/lib/kafka/data
  - /home/certs/san:/etc/kafka/secrets
networks:
  cms-overlay:
    external: true
```

In above docker compose yml files I have tried setting up multiple SSL listeners.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Added compose files in text. Could you please review and tell me any possible solution for this issue. I have stuck in this issues for many days.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't used SSL Kafka in Docker, so cannot provide much help here.